# How to write to the local file using Gecko FX

Tags: javascript, c#, firefox, gecko, geckofx

I want to start an html file located locally (no web server) and write it to a local file with that html file.
But the browser to use is geckoFX embedded in C # Form.
How can I write to local files with geckoFX?
If it is impossible with geckoFX, is it possible with EO.WebBrowser?
Operating environment: .Net FrameWork 3.5, GeckoFX v 45.0.7.0
In the html file located locally (no web server) we used the following code, but "Error: TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined"

```
 filename = (ua.indexOf ('windows')! = -1? 'C: \\ temp \\': '/ temp /') + filename;
 netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege ('UniversalXPConnect');
var file = Components.classes ['@ mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath (filename);
var fileStream = Components.classes ['@ mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1'].createInstance (Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);          

fileStream.init (
            file,
            0x02 | 0x08, 0664, 0);
          var converterStream = Components
            .classes ['@ mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1']
            .createInstance (Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);
          converterStream.init (
            fileStream,
            'UTF-8',
            content.length,
            Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream.DEFAULT_REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER
          );
          converterStream.writeString (content);

          converterStream.close ();
          fileStream.close ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to files from anywhere by using:

```cs
File.WriteAllText("file.path", "contents_to_write");
```

or for bytes:

```cs
File.WriteAllBytes("file.path", byte[]);
```

where `byte[]` could be replace with the byte array to write.

**Hopefully, this helps!**